# Is O(nk(log(k))) algorithm same as O(n(log(k)))

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o, time-complexity

I was asked to give an algorithm that was supposed to be `O(n(log(k)))`
k is the number of arrays and n is the total number of elements in all of these. I had to sort the arrays.
Minus the details I came up with an algorithm that does the job for in `klog(k)` times the total number of elements. i.e. `O(nk(log(k)))`

Also in this case k is much smaller than n so it wont be n^2(logn) (in case k and n were almost same)right?

Comment: No they are not the same.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about computer science and belongs on cs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you describe the question both `k` and `n` are input parameters. If that is the case then the answer to your question is

'No, `O(n*k *log(k))` is not the same as `O(n*log(k))`'.

It is not that hard to see that the first one grows faster than the second one, but it is even more obvious if you fix the value of `n.` Consider n begin a constant say `1`. Than it is more obvious that `O(k*log(k))` is not the same as `O(log(k))`.

Answer (score 2):

Well, no, it's not the same. If `k` is a variable (as opposed to a constant) in the complexity expression then `O(nk(log(k))) > O(n(log(k)))`.

That is because there is no constant `C` such that `Cn(log(k)) > kn(log(k))` for **every** `n, k`.